# How to track github pull request review line comments across commits?

Tags: git, github

In the following scenario:

- A developer creates a pull request.
- A reviewer adds PR review line comments to the PR conversation.
- The developer fixes the issues by creating and pushing a new commit.

Then the PR review line comments appear as "outdated" in the PR conversation, as they should.

However, as the reviewer, what I'd like to see is the comments in the context of the latest commit.

For example, viewing "difference from last reviewed commit", one can see the "old" code as it was when it was reviewed, compared to the latest commit code. It would have been very helpful to see the last review's comments attached to the "old" code, allowing the reviewer to decide whether the line comment was fixed, or is no longer relevant, or still applies to the latest code, or needs to be modified, or whatever.

The best way I found for now is to:

- Open a view of the "old" commit, which shows the attached PR review line comments, in one window.
- Show the diff from the last reviewed commit in a second window, which, alas, does not show the attached PR review line comments.
- Go over the diff, manually locating where each PR review line comment was.

That's pretty tedious and error-prone. Is there a better way? Hopefully I am just missing some obvious (or not so obvious :-) GitHub feature...

Googling shows me a lot of people complaining about GitHub code reviews, and some add-on tools that do wonderful things (such as treating each review comment as a task, which is a great idea).

I couldn't find any tools that helps track the line comments across commits though. Possibly such a tool exists and I just missed it?

EDIT: Wording.

Comment: I am wondering the same thing and since this topic is 3 years old now, did you find a better way? :)

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any other way either to do it with Github. I totally agree with your frustration.
I eventually found a tool (that is free unless you are an organization) called **reviewable** that solves this. I use it for all my projects with my team for code reviews.
It is AMAZING and is really great and it integrates flawlessly with Github. It is very intuitive.

Here is the link to their app: https://reviewable.io/